# Design a circuit for given transfer characteristic

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, dc

Design a circuit for the following transfer characteristic with diodes(Vf = 0.7 V), resistors and voltage sources:
[image]

**My try:** I think this circuit should work:
[image]

In general it behaves like that. Vout is constant for voltages less than some number, linear for an interval and again linear for voltages greater than some number with different slope but I couldn't figure out values for voltage sources and resistors. When I set them so that they fit the transfer characteristic in an interval, in the other intervals doesn't work. I don't know whether I should change everything or there is an elegant way for the determining values of resistors and voltage sources.

Comment: What does \$2^V\$ actually mean?

Comment: @Andyaka It means 2V. Sorry for that.

Comment: The values of the components in the circuit also matter. There's V3, is it 3V? Or -3V? There's a diode in series that drops 0.7 V, so should the 3 V be 2.3 V then? Or 3.7 V?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie As I said, I've tried to set values so that Vout fits the transfer function in an interval but then it didn't work for other intervals.

Comment: Transfer characteristic, not transfer function

Comment: @Chu fixed, thanks.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Break the problem down into a series of models and post a schematic for each one into your question using CircuitLab as shown in my comment above. (Step 1) Draw the circuit to give the sloping part of the line (allowing it to extend to infinity in both directions.) You're going to need to assign some resistor values. Use values in the hundreds of ohms range and choose numbers for easy mental arithmetic.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Thanks @Transistor for the hints. Here is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f72EkV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't know whether there is a way to implement ideal diode in CircuitLab but characteristics of this circuit is same as the question's plot.

Comment: Did you run the simulator to check? You can do a DC sweep of Vin. Try from -8 to 8, step 0.1. You haven't finished yet!

Comment: Make that -12 to 12, step 0.1. Post a screengrab of your result for proof! Hints: I gave you step 1 which you've solved with R1 and R2. Step 2: add in the components needed to give the -3 V clamp. Step 3: add in the components to give the 1/3 slope when Vin > 4 V. Post a screengrab of each step.